# Auto-resizing problem in scrollview subviews

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have a scrollview on a `UIView` and a series of `UIImageViews` are placed on the scrollview in a serial manner. My problem is that the image views are not resizing when the device is rotated. In the `viewWillAppear`, I added

```
imageView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    FirstScrollView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does the entire view rotates correctly? does the scrollView itself rotates correctly? (check this by setting it's background color). Does the viewController's view is set to autoResize Subviews?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with Interface builder.

Comment: I tried it.I have enabled all the arrow marks in the interface builder.Still not working.